# My SQL Not Equal Not Working

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get data from table1 comparing its field with table2 in which both values are not equal

### eg:

```
news:
--
id, title
1   test
2   teeest
3   tet

newsseen:
id, newsId
1   1
2   2
```

Following is my query with `!=`,

```
SELECT n.id, n.title, n.CreatedOn FROM news n , newsseen ns WHERE n.id != ns.newsId group by n.id;
```

It returns all data from news table instead of only 3rd row

But the following query works correct if i check with `=`

```
SELECT n.id, n.title, n.CreatedOn FROM news n , newsseen ns WHERE n.id = ns.newsId group by n.id;
```

It returns only 1st 2 rows.

May i know why and can get a solution for that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doing the correct thing.  What you want is to do a "set-based" equality and see if nothing matches.  This requires a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT n.id, n.title, n.CreatedOn
FROM news n LEFT JOIN
     newsseen ns 
     ON n.id = ns.newsId 
WHERE ns.newsId IS NULL;
```

I see no reason for a `GROUP BY`.

And, I should add my usual:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit, proper `JOIN` syntax.

(You can also readily express this with `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN`, but your approach suggests `LEFT JOIN`.  The three should have similar performance.)

Answer (score 2):

You looking for `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT n.id, n.title, n.CreatedOn 
FROM news n 
WHERE Not exists (select 1 from newsseen ns where n.id = ns.newsId )
```

---

In your first query, For the first `Id` in `news` table (ie) `1`. According to your condition `n.id != ns.newsId` there is one record in `newsseen` table which is not equal (ie) `newsId = 2` so `ID=1` will be returned.

similarly for `Id=2` in `news` table there is a non matching record (ie) `newsId=1` is present in `newsseen` table so `Id=2` will also be returned.

for `Id=3` in `news` table both the records are not matching in `newsseen` so `Id=3` will also be returned

Comment: without sub-query please?

Comment: @VinothBabu - Already Gordan posted answer using `Left Join`. But why without `sub-query` ? I feel `NOT EXISTS` is the right way to do this

Comment: @VinothBabu - No it will not at least in this case. You can check the performance of both the queries by running with your real time data

Comment: If the subquery returns more than 2k data then ll it work? also what is that select 1 will return in sub-query (i.e) newsId?

Comment: @VinothBabu - Of course it will work. 2k is not a huge count at all. As I said earlier You can check the performance of both the queries by running with your real time data

Comment: Thanks Man. :) also what is that select 1 will return in sub-query (i.e) newsId?

Comment: @VinothBabu - It is just a static value to the existence of a record for the filters we have applied inside the sub-query. It can be anything even your name ;)